# MVC 5 ApplicationUser always null except for logged in user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have modified ApplicationUser to include custom properties and included it in a single dbcontext with the rest of my models. Everything is working fine with the account functionality.

I have Note Model that includes ApplicationUser Author.

When I try to get a list of all notes, they are all returned to a list. Author is correct if the Author is the logged in user. Otherwise, the Author is null.

I have tried this by logging in as different users and I can only ever get an author if it is the logged in user.

I have been searching for a fix for this for hours and cant find any mention of anyone running into this.

I am not sure what code I can provide, because this is working to an extent. I figure there has to be a setting I am overlooking that is preventing users from accessing other users information. I could see this being an option and I understand how it could be useful, but this is being retrieved by admins anyway.

MVC 5 and EF6 are being used.

Edit:
Here is the linq query to get Notes:

```
var notes = db.Notes.ToList();
```

Here is how the author looks in the Notes Model:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Created By")]
    public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
```

I am getting the list of all notes successfully. It's just the author for any notes not created but the logged in user have the author as null.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to get a list of all notes?

Answer (score 0):

It clicked right after I posted this and realized that the ApplicationUser Author should be a virtual property.